# NoClassDefFoundError with Google Play Services 9.2.0 (Admob)

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, proguard

I'm working on a legacy project in Eclipse and need to update Google Play services, specifically Analytics and Admob.

Upon trying to get 9.2.0 the old way by copying the JAR file from the Android SDK `/extras/` folder, I found that's no longer possible due to Google switching over to AAR files supporting Android Studio.

I found [this GitHub project](https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-README) with all of the Google Play Service AAR modules expanded into individual Android projects. I've downloaded and imported the appropriate projects for Analytics and Admob as indicated here (https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-README).

My project successfully compiles with no errors, so all classes are accessible and linked properly.

**However, upon launching on my Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1 I constantly receive this upon launch:**

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze>
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze>
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze>
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 22307
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zze
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzm.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzm.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzm.zziw(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzad.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.AndroidLauncher$1.handleMessage(AndroidLauncher.java:102)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Line 102 refers to this, which occurs at startup:**

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

---

From my research, all I see are references to an (old) bug that effected Gingerbread devices, but I don't believe that applies here.

---

**Edit:** My build.gradle file as requested. Not sure if relevant since I'm not using this to link a dependency to the Google Play Services, but here it is anyway:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.11.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    ext {
        appName = 'sticknodes'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.5'
        roboVMVersion = '1.14.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":android-pro") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:1.14.0"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":ios-pro") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.14"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Gradle file?

Comment: @nitinsh99 Sure, edited my question with it.

Comment: Could you try adding: compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0" in your dependencies? Make sure to clean your project and resync gradle.

Comment: @nitinsh99 I was playing with this before. I did as you suggested and Gradle didn't download anything new. So I changed the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to 2.0.0 from 1.3.1. Now it just gives me this error upon trying to refresh Gradle dependencies: http://pastebin.com/pHz7Tn4F

Comment: Went ahead and changed the wrapper version as the error said, had to clean some other stuff up to to get it to refresh dependencies. Still didn't download anything new so project is just showing "cannot be resolved to a type" errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So next day I added the Android library "play-services-basement" as a dependency to my project and everything worked. Didn't realize I needed to add that as a dependency directly to my own project since admob/analytics projects implicitly added it as well.